# Tweet with a random generated number

Tags: python, random, numbers

I'm a newbie to Python actually i want a script to tweet automatically with some random numbers but unfortunately the script always generate a same random number everytime so it leads to a duplicated tweet after some time

**Here is my code :**

```
import random



randomlist = random.sample(range(0, 99), 99)
int = random.choice(randomlist)
string = f"{int}"

for i in range(len(list)):
    try:
        
        api.update_status(status =list[i]+" "+ string+" #twitter") 
        print("successfully tweeted")
        sleep(360)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

I don't know what's wrong in this script but I faced a same random number genrated every time instead of different one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, you're shadowing both `int` and `list` functions by setting variables to their name. Second, `random.sample(range(0, 99), 99)` makes no sense if you're using `random.choice` to just pull one randomly from the list. You might as well just use `random.randint` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are generating your random number **outside** your for loop, so you generate the random number once and inside the for loop you are simply accessing the same number over and over again. Also, if you simply want to generate a random integer I would suggest using the random.randint function. So, the whole loop would look like

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    try:
        #insert more hashtags if you want to here
        string = f"{random.randint(0,99)}"
        api.update_status(status =list[i]+" "+ string+" #twitter") 
        print("successfully tweeted")
        sleep(360)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

(and you could delete your previous random number generation) and you should be able to generate a different random number for every iteration.

Edit: Edited to improve code as @HampusLarsson suggested

Comment: You seem to have a solution in plan for him. Could you show how you would improve his code in your answer as well?

Comment: I know this might seem petty, but could you also show how the restructured loop would look like in his code? Keep the explanation, just add more verbosity in the answer!